Kummer extension corresponding to a cohomology class
Let $F$ be a (CM) number field, $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb F_p$, $F_S$ be the maximal algebraic extension of $F$ unramified outside $S$. In the 10 author paper p.151, the following are written:

Assume that $\kappa$ represents a cohomology class in $H^1(F_S /F,k(1))$. The cohomology class of $\kappa$ corresponds to a Kummer
extension $F (\zeta_p, y)$ with $y^p \in F (\zeta_p)$.

May I ask how does $\kappa$ give rise to the Kummer extension?
A Kummer theory statement I know is that $H^1(Gal(\bar K/K,\mu_n)=K^\times/K^{\times n}$, but this does not seem to be very relevant here. In case it helps, $\kappa$ is nontrivial and $\zeta_p\notin F$ in their case and their next sentence is

Since $\kappa$ is nontrivial and $\zeta_p\notin F$ , this extension $F (\zeta_p, y)$ is not abelian over $F$ .


As stated at the beginning of $\S 6.2.1$, I’m assuming that $S$ contains all places above $p$. I’m not sure what the claim means if $k\neq \mathbb{F}_p$, so I’ll assume $k=\mathbb{F}_p$, so that $k(1)=\mu_p$ as Galois modules.
Let $K=\overline{F}$, one has the exact sequence $1 \rightarrow \mu_p \rightarrow K^{\times} \rightarrow K^{\times} \rightarrow 1$ (where the second-to-last arrow is $z \mapsto z^p$) of $Gal(K/F’)$-modules where $F \subset F’ \subset K$, so the cohomology LES and Hilbert 90 yield an isomorphism $(F’)^{\times}/(F’)^{\times p} \rightarrow H^1(K/F’,k(1))$, and this isomorphism is compatible with restriction.
Now, $H^1(F_S/F,k(1))$ identifies (by inflation-restriction) with the kernel of the restriction $H^1(K/F,k(1)) \rightarrow H^1(K/F_S,k(1))$, whence it identifies with the kernel $U$ of $F^{\times}/F^{\times p} \rightarrow F_S^{\times}/F_S^{\times p}$.
More precisely, $U$ is the collection of cosets $zF^{\times p} \subset F^{\times}$ such that at every finite place $v \notin S$, $v(z)$ is a multiple of $p$.
So, let $\kappa \in H^1(F_S/F,\mu_p)$, then $\kappa$ corresponds to a coset $zF^{\times p} \in U$ and the extension is $F(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{z})$.
Another way, perhaps easier, to formulate this relationship (although it’s basically the same) is the following: let $\kappa \in H^1(F_S/F,\mu_p)$ be nonzero. Then its restriction $\kappa’$ to $H^1(F_S/F(\zeta_p),\mu_p)$ is nonzero since $[F(\zeta_p):F] \mid p-1$ is coprime to $p$.
Therefore, $\kappa’$ identifies to a non-zero morphism $Gal(\overline{F}/F(\zeta_p)) \rightarrow \mu_p$ that factors through $Gal(F_S/F(\zeta_p))$. So its kernel is of the form $Gal(F_S/F’)$ for some abelian extension $F’/F(\zeta_p)$ of degree $p$. By Kummer theory, $F’=F(\zeta_p,y)$ for some $y \in F’$ with $y^p \in F(\zeta_p)$.
